# Need to install VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.3.8 in CentOS 6.3

Tags: virtualbox, centos

My host system is OSX 10.9.2 and I'm running VirtualBox 4.3.8.

In a Hadoop class I took recently, we were provided with a VM disk image preloaded with CentOS 6.3 and a lot of Hadoop-related software.  This is what I have to work with.

As it stands, I don't have bidirectional cut/paste or any of the other goodies that VBOX Guest Additions provide.

I recently posted in this forum [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120975/29365) about upgrading/updating (sorry, I don't understand the distinction, although I understand that there *is* one) from CentOS 6.3 to 6.5.  The only reason that I think I succeeded is that CentOS would no longer boot to the desktop.  *(It seems possible that it was no longer compatible with the Hadoop software that was on the disk.)* So apparently that wasn't the solution to my problem.

**I know that it is possible get VBGA working for this disk image: someone else in my class had OSX and VirtualBox, and was able to get past the problem I'm about to describe.**

Here's what I've done so far:

- DL’ed and installed VBOX 4.3.8 for OSX from
  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
- DL’ed http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.8/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.8-92456.vbox-extpack
- Doubleclicked the file, the VB Manager said “The extension pack is
  already installed with the same version, would you like reinstall
  it?”  I reinstalled, just for grins.
- Booted, ran `yum info kernel`, saw that V2.6.32r279.el6 was “installed”, and that V2.6.32r431.5.1.el6 was “available”.  I don't know enough about Linux to know if that means CentOS 6.3 and 6.5, or if it's something else entirely.
- Also noted that Guest Additions functionality was not there.
- Used **VirtualBox VM > Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image…** to mount the CD (it appeared on the desktop)
- Ran **VBoxLinuxAdditions.run**
- Building the main Guest Additions module … FAILED
- /var/log/vboxadd-install.log: “Unable to find sources of current Linux kernel.  Specify KERN_DIR= and run make again.”

Off to Google.  [This post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=44261) most closely resembled my problem.  However, it differs enough (Windows, i686, VBOX 4.3.6) to make me afraid I’ll just wander off into another morass.

Could someone provide baby-step guidance from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have found the solution by now.  In case someone else stumbles across this, perhaps this will help:

```
# yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers perl
```

There are other dependencies for building the kernel modules, but those should be well documented.  My specific problem (due to using the minimal install) was not having perl.

Comment: I abandoned this problem long ago, so I can't verify. (But thanks, hopefully it will help someone.)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install the following:

```
yum install gcc kernel-devel
```

The gcc is important too.

After that I simply ran

```
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

And after a reboot the whole functionality was there.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I faced with Red Hat Linux. What I just did was, just installed the gcc packages and it's dependencies using

```
yum install gcc* -y
```

After that all went correctly and I can able to 
installed vbox guest additions. Now all works fine for me. Hope it'll work for you..

Comment: I don't really see the point in writing this answer as it was mentioned in a few other answers that also noted the need for `kernel-headers` or `kernel-devel`.

Comment: While at the time of installing vbox guest additions, I also faced the same problem and that clearly says that there I have to install gcc package. So, I installed gcc packages and it's dependencies first and after that I [can] install  vbox guest additions.